# Mass deformations in D-brane systems

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, yang-mills, topological-field-theory, branes

It is well known that the worldvolume theory of $N$ coincident D$p$-branes is given by the $U(N)$ Yang-Mills theory in $(p+1)$-dimensions. One important feature of this setup is the possibility of producing a $U(N) \rightarrow U(1)^{N}$ symmetry breaking pattern by separating the branes along a common transverse direction.

There is, however a case of a slight generalization of this setup that puzzles me; concretely, how to localize to the Higgs branch of a system $N$ coincident D4-branes wrapping a 4-cycle inside a toric Calabi-Yau manifold threefold. I have read several times about the possibility to produce a BRST-exact mass deformation of the D4 worldvolume theory to deform the 4-cycle $\mathcal{C}$ to a torus-equivariant configuration (see for example section 2.1 in [Crystals and Intersecting Branes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0607032) or [Two Dimensional Yang-Mills, Black Holes and Topological Strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406058)).

Problem: I have not a rigorous understanding about how this mechanism actually works beyond heuristics, nor a precise list of the conditions under this procedure is valid. The papers I posted discuss interesting examples, but I'm interested in the discussion in more generality, if possible.

The following cite [Crystals and Intersecting Branes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0607032) (third paragraph in page 8, section 3) suggests that the requirement of being very ample (talking about a representative of the homology class of $\mathcal{C}$) is the only one needed.

> Any collection of intersecting D4 branes whose total homology class is very ample
> can be deformed in the normal directions, generically producing a single D4 brane
> wrapping a complicated surface.

A very remarkable statement!

***Question:*** **How can I check that explicitly?**